# Is there a way to delete a row from mysql after a certain amount of time counting from insert time

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have a requirement to delete a row after 24 hours from its creation time. Is there a way in PHP/MySQL to do this?

The time must count from the insertion time of the row and after 24 hours it must be deleted. Although we can write `cron` to check for every minute, when there are not many rows added `cron` will run without use. Is there some other mechanism to do it?

Comment: Maybe have a process schedule to scan the database for outdated rows?

Comment: Check my answer, others may be able to propose any other solution if you can tell what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: just run the `cron` there is no reason not to really.  one call per minute is not that much load if the query is written fairly well.  Or like one of the answers below suggests, `mysql event`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your mySQL version >=  5.1.6 , there is a good feature intended for use in such cases - mySQL events.

Here is an example of usage - http://phpmaster.com/working-with-mysql-events/

Comment: so this is like cron in mysql...we will need to check at specific intervals? It will also have same effect as cron...running unnecessarily if no records are there...I wonder if it is more efficient than cron

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to check on regular intervals. Another approach is to decide whether the existing row is 24hrs old or not. If the row is more than 24hrs old then don't perform the action otherwise do it. Meanwhile you can run your cron say every 30 minutes to delete rows which are more than 24hrs old.

Answer (score -1):

create a task on the server using Scheduled Tasks (or SQL Scheduler, or your favorite Scheduling tool) to execute it at whatever interval you need.

Comment: You're just repeating what the OP said he didn't want to do.  And I think you're talking about SQL Server and not MySQL.