# delete rows from a table using MySQL Scheduler

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table called: "regkeys". This table has two columns: "keyCat" and "keyNum". In my web-app I have a keygen module that adds a key(1134fb) and a category(mds or dts, etc.) into this table.

What I want to accomplish is this: after issuing (adding into the db) a key, I'd like to create a MySQL event to delete the keys that stay/stayed in my table longer than 2 days (or so), this way expiring the keys (for example: - from the time it was created, counting 2 days, each key has to be deleted, having certain keys getting deleted sooner or later than others, depending on when they were created). I looked at the [MySQL's API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html), but I need some help with the logic. I do not know how to tell the event to delete only the keys that were stored in for 2 days (or so). I was hoping somebody could give me a quick example or direct me to a clear tutorial.

Thank you very much in advance.

Edited: I think I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860857/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-row-from-mysql-after-a-certain-amount-of-time-countin) that helps a bit with my problem. I think I was going about it the wrong way (key based). Since every key and key category get inserted into a row, the scheduler should deal with rows instead of keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution:

1. Enabled the event_scheduler in the db like this: `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`
2. Added a timestamp column in my table using MySQL default values
3. I created an event,  `CREATE EVENT <name>`
4. Called the event to run on a schedule like so: `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 20 SECOND`
5. Add the SQL query to the event: `DO DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE <time_stamp_column> < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman, Edited, and thanks for your comment ;0). I always vote-up good questions,answers or observations.